# Strange behaviour of quote-environment after wrapfigure

Tags: footnotes, wrapfigure

Using wrapfigure in the main text and just after that in a footnote, then the quote environment behave strangely: too narrow or shifted away.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{mwe}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{5cm}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}%{000057684_17150122_1062073_02.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[3]
\footnote{%
\lipsum[2]
\begin{wrapfigure}[8]{l}{2cm}
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure}\lipsum[4]
}
\newpage
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[3]
\end{quote}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

Removing one of the "wrapfigure" then one gets the usual quote. So it seems that the wrapfigure changes some lengths. Any idea?

Comment: as documented: "You must not specify a wrapfigure in any type of list environment or or immediately before or immediately after one.", and quote is a list environment.

Comment: I have seen this in the documentation of wrapfigure. But In my case you can add any amount of text, even new sections ...  after the footnote, but nothing changes. I made all kind of tests.

Comment: Hm. I will look later, I never dared to put a wrapfig in a footnote (and I never put so much text in a footnote that I actually had to consider the use of wrapfig there).

Comment: You probably have never been working with historians. In their research most of the relevant material is in footnotes. And I could not convince them to use endnotes which would simplify a lot the presentation. If you have time have a look at https://eterna.unibas.ch/index.php/publbez/index

Comment: you have two wrapfigures in the same paragraph (as the footnote starts at the end of the one with the main wrapfig. If I move the footnote the quote behaves again.

Comment: Thanks, Ulrike! So it seems that if a wrapfigure appears in a footnote, then the footnote has to be in paragraph without wrapfigure. On the other hand, a new paragraph in the footnote before wrapfigure does not help. I solved the problem by using wrapfigure in the text and wrapstuff in the footnotes. Not very elegant, but it works. Thanks again for you help.

Comment: the problem is that wrapfig changes locally \linewidth and \@totalleftmargin. It tries to restore the correct values, but when you nest two wrapfigs, it fails. The quote behaves again, if you use `\makeatletter \linewidth=\textwidth \@totalleftmargin=0pt  \makeatother` just before it.